# при втором ajax post запросе выводит ошибку 500 (internal server error)

Tags: ajax, node.js, post, mongoose, express

```
// SERVER

router.post('/rations/new', (req, res) => {
  var options = {
      weekCalories: req.body.weekcalories,
      weekDay: req.body.weekday,
      foodName: req.body.rationname,
      foodCalories: req.body.rationcalories,
      foodDescription: req.body.rationdescription
  }
  api.addRation(options);
  res.send(options);
});

// api.js

function createRation() {

    let ration = new Schema({
        weekCalories: String,
        weekDay: String,
        foodName: String,
        foodDescription: String,
        foodCalories: String
    });
    return mongoose.model('Rations', ration);

}


module.exports.addRation = (options) => {
    createRation().insertMany(options);
}

// CLIENT

$.ajax({
        url: '/rations/new',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "weekcalories": $("#weekCalories").val(),
            "weekday": $("#weekDay").val(),
            "rationname": $("#foodName").val(),
            "rationcalories": $("#foodCalories").val(),
            "rationdescription": $("#foodDescription").val()
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

```html
<form action="/rations/new" method="POST" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="weekCalories">Калорий за неделю</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="weekCalories">
                            <option>3000 ккал</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="weekDay">День недели</label>
                        <select id="weekDay" class="form-control">
                            <option>Понедельник</option>
                            <option>Вторник</option>
                            <option>Среда</option>
                            <option>Четверг</option>
                            <option>Пятница</option>
                            <option>Суббота</option>
                            <option>Воскресенье</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="foodName">Имя</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foodName" placeholder="Завтрак 1..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="foodCalories">Калорий</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foodCalories" placeholder="100 ккал..">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="foodDescription">Описание</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="foodDescription" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" id="Add">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @RomanC Терминал: POST /rations/new 500 3.185 ms - 1997 в консоле браузера: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/rations/new 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Это сообщение лишь только говорит, что ошибка на сервере и никакого сообщения обошибке.

Comment: @RomanC извиняюсь, но забыл подметить, что в этот же момент не работает mongoose, т.е не добавляются данные. Именно при втором запросе, тем не менее меняю значения input чтоб были уникальными.